# extract multiple decimal numbers and trailing string from a string php

Tags: php, regex

I got strings in a file which look like this (coma or dot is used as the decimal point):

```
$str = "12,50  EUR, 3,5%";
$str = "12,50EUR, 3,5%";
$str = "12,50EUR,3,5%";
$str = "2,5%";
$str = "8,75  EUR";
$str = "12.50  EUR, 3,5%";
$str = "12,50  EUR, 3.5%";
$str = "2.5%"
$str = "8.75  EUR";
$str = "8.75EUR";
$str = "8,75EUR";
```

I would like to be able to extract from each string the numerical values followed by whatever symbol follows the number stripping out any white spaces or in between characters.

As an example the resulting associative array for

```
$str = "12,50  EUR, 3,5%";
```

should like like this (the resulting value always uses the dot as a decimal separator regardless of what it was before):

```
array = {
[12.75] => 'EUR',
[3.5] => '%'
}
```

Comment: Your desired output is wrong. What if the amount and percent are equal? Please reconsider it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$str []= "12,50  EUR, 3,5%";
$str []= "1EUR,2%";
$str []= "12,50EUR, 3,5%";
$str []= "12,50EUR,3,5%";
$str []= "2,5%";
$str []= "8,75  EUR";
$str []= "12.50  EUR, 3,5%";
$str []= "12,50  EUR, 3.5%";
$str []= "2.5%";
$str []= "8.75  EUR";
$str []= "8.75EUR";
$str []= "8,75EUR";

foreach ($str as $string) {
preg_match_all("/([0-9]+,*\.*[0-9]*\s*[A-Za-z%]*)/", $string, $results);
$ret= array();
if (isset($results[0][0])) {
        preg_match("/([0-9]+,*\.*[0-9]*)(\s*[A-Za-z%]*)/", $results[0][0], $res);
        $num = str_replace(",", ".", $res[1]);
        $sym = trim($res[2]);
        $ret[$num] = $sym;
}
if (isset($results[0][1])) {
        preg_match("/([0-9]+,*\.*[0-9]*)(\s*[A-Za-z%]*)/", $results[0][1], $res);
        $num = str_replace(",", ".", $res[1]);
        $sym = trim($res[2]);
        $ret[$num] = $sym;
}

var_dump($ret);
}
```

Comment: I think this is a good starting point but it may not always be EUR or % following the number. Can this be improved?

Comment: I would add to the above that also it needs to be able to handle integer values as part of the string like 2% 5EUR